# Run async task in class that extends Threading - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio

I've created a python class that extends `threading` and uses a library that runs `asyncio` tasks.

```
import threading
from app.food import recipes

class Mixer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    
    async def run(self):
        while True:
           ingredients = await recipes.get()
```

When I run the code I get following error:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Mixer.run' was never awaited

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`run` in Thread class is not supposed to be a coroutine. It is just called as is. Not waited for.
It is called `obj.run()` not by a `await obj.run()` nor `asyncio.run(self.run)` or whatever.

When you extend a class, you are supposed to overload methods while keeping the same interface (that's the whole point of extending/overloading). Here, you are not. Your are replacing a method that is meant to be just ran, by a one that is supposed to be awaited.

What exactly are you trying to do?
There are already, in asyncio, some functions to transform a (implicit) thread into a coroutine (for non-asyncio blocking tasks, that you want to "await").
See `to_thread()` method, for example.
Or other functions to interact with threads. Depending on what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: I am going to use the ThreadPoolExecutor to execute the asyncio task.

Comment: I am not very familiar with that. But I doubt it requires "Thread" with awaitable runs. (I put quotes around "Thread", because Thread with awaitable runs are no longer Threads). In fact, at first glance to ThreadPoolExecutor, they seems to be to be another implementation of asyncio tasks (maybe they are internally implemented with async/await. Or with threads. But in example codes, I don't see any mention neither of asyncio, await, async, nor of thread module. It looks like it is transparent to the user)

Comment: In your case, I get that you have a ``recipes.get`` method that takes a while (probably because it is getiting things from internet), and you don't want to block waiting it.

Comment: For that, you could use ThreadPoolExecutor, and simply pass a plain, old, normal, blocking function, without any async/await or threads. That "recipe.get()" and block. And threadpoolexecutor will make it concurrent for you (probably, I take that from the name, by lauching each task in a thread)

Comment: Or you could do that yourself, by creating a thread that does ``recipe.get()``, lauching several of them yourself if needed, and then joining them.

Comment: Or you could implement an awaitable version of ``recipe.get`` (for example, using asynco to_thread), and then using asyncio tasks to await the execution of several concurrent ``async recipe.get``

Comment: The recipes.get() is an async task that needs to be waited for because it gets stuff from a web server.

Comment: I am going to use the ThreadPoolExecutor to execute `recipe.get()` in  asyncio task. –

Comment: But my feeling (and again, I am no specialist here. I've never throroughly thought about this. I've just used a few times both methods - async or threads - when I had been in need to wait 2 things at a time), is that you are mixing in the same questions 3 (threadpoolexecutor, threads and async/await) different ways to execute several blocking tasks and wait for all of them. My feeling is that you may use one of them, but that you don't need to use all 3 of them (even if, internally, they probably use each other)

Comment: The solution was simple.
`result = asyncio.run(recipes.get)` declaring `def run(self):` as NOT async method